# python package installed in wrong working enviroment

Tags: python, spyder, python-module

I installed sklearn using pip install.
whoever I can't use it, I think because it installed in different working enviroment.
The following code is for more information.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
~\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\python.exe
```

```
pip install sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in ~\spyder-6\envs\spyder-runtime\lib\site-packages (0.0.post11)
```

I use spyder to code in.

I tried this:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

However I received this:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Comment: Did you restart spyder after you installed the package?

Comment: Try `pip install scikit-learn` instead.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, this did not seam to work